# Number of arrangements of $n$ couples around a circular table with restriction

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

A group of $n$ couples (a total of $2n$ people) sit at a circular table. Arrangements that differ by any rotation of the seating positions are considered to be the same. Find a formula for the number of seatings where no woman sits beside her partner?

Comment: By complement, we find the number of seating where there are one couples sits together. We choose one couples from n couple and fixed them at two seats. So, the number to arrange is 2(2n-2)!. So, we can find the number of seating where no woman sits beside her partner are (2n-1)!-2(2n-2)!= (2n-3)*(2n-2)!.

Comment: Linking: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374367

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). We have $n$ conditions for the $n$ couples sitting next to each other. If one of the conditions is fulfilled, we can regard the corresponding couple as a single person to be seated and include a factor $2$ for the two orders in which the couple can sit. So there are $2^k(2n-k-1)!$ different arrangements that satisfy $k$ particular conditions, and thus

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k2^k(2n-k-1)!
$$

different arrangements that satisfy none of the conditions. This is [OEIS sequence A129348](https://oeis.org/A129348).