# Combinatorics Question Involving Seating n Couples at a table with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways are there to seat n couples around a circular table such that no couple sits next to each other?

I'm really not sure where to start with this one...I was able to find another question that is similar, but I'm not sure if the answer is the same since the question restricts the couples so they can't sit across from one another as opposed to next to each other like in my question. Here is the link to that question's page on stack exchange: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374367/problem-about-n-couples-sitting-at-a-round-table](http://Seating%20n%20couples%20such%20that%20they%20are%20not%20across%20each%20other)

Comment: Question seems to be quite popular today. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978566/ways-to-seat-n-couples-around-a-circular-table-with-restriction and the other questions linked there.

Comment: Have you followed up on that link?

Comment: I have thank you!!

Comment: Good! Now, here's what you can do. If you now know how to solve the problem, you can write up and post an answer. Or, if you are convinced that your question is a duplicate of one that has been asked and answered before, you can vote to close your question as a duplicate. If you don't have the points needed to vote to close, you can just leave a comment indicating which question yours duplicates, and then someone else can come along and vote to close it.