# How many ways can 3 couples sit on round table if no husband sits in front of each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374367/problem-about-%24n%24-couples-sitting-at-a-round-table) if the couple can't sit in front of each other, but it didn't help too much.
If possible I would like a proof using principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Edit with a more formal definition: If we have couples $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ we want for $i \neq j$ that the pair $x_i$ and $x_j$ doesn't sit in front of each other (ie they can't have two people between they in both sides)

Comment: I take it we are to assume each couple is one male one female.

Comment: What does "no husband sits in front of each other" mean?  Are you saying that, if we number the seats $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and put a man in seat $1$, we must then put a woman in seat $4$ (and then the same for $(2,5)$ and $(3,6)$)?  Something else?

Comment: And what constitutes an arrangement?  Does rotation make a new arrangement or not?  What about reflection?

Comment: Is this the *exact* wording of the question taken from a book or given by your teacher ?

Comment: A more formal definition: If we have couples $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ we want for $i \neq j$ that the pair $x_i$ and $x_j$ doesn't sit in front of each other (ie they can't have two people between they in both sides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice there are $6!/6= 5!$ ways to sit $6$ people around a table. Then we make the observation that if a husband $H_1$ is across from another husband $H_2$ then the third husband $H_3$ must be sitting next to $H_1$ or $H_2$. So there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick the pair of husbands to sit across from each other. Then $2$ options for the remaining husband for which husband he wants to sit next to and another $2$ options for which side. Lastly there are $3!$ ways to sit the $3$ women in the remaining spots.

Hence $3\cdot 2 \cdot 2\cdot 6= 72$ ways for a pair of husbands to sit across from one another.

Therefore, we have $120-72=48$ ways to sit around a round table so that no husband sits across from another.

Comment: This combinatorial solution makes a lot of sense to me and I think is the right answer. But how can I use this information to make proof using the principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Comment: @canelas This is the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle argument since it is not possible for two pairs of husbands to be opposite to each other.